# Image not Displaying even after following effbot

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add in an image to a screen and its not displaying.

Followed other Stack overflow solutions and the Effbot solution and neither worked. Ive moved the image around and it still isnt displaying so its not where its displaying. Not getting any Error messages either.

```
image = PhotoImage("newspaper-extra-computer-icons-breaking-newsnewspaper.jpg")
image_label = Label(news_aggregator,image = image)
image_label.image = image
image_label.place(x=400,y = 200)
```

Just expecting the image to be displayed.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Two things: 1st you have to pass the file name as a keyword argument `image=PhotoImage(file="...")`. 2nd, if you need to display `jpg`, you need to install `PIL` and use `ImageTk.Photoimage` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are missing `file=` in `PhotoImage()`.

Try this:

`PhotoImage(file='path_to_image.gif')`

That said tkinter only supports a hand full of formats.

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files

For working with other formats you will need PIL.

> If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30 formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:

You can see all there [here on the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

For your file try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()


image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="newspaper-extra-computer-icons-breaking-newsnewspaper.jpg")
image_label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
image_label.image = image
image_label.place(x=400, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Keep in mind due to you using `place()` the above code will not be showing the image as it is off frame. You will need to expand the window.